# Maven and SpringBoot debugging what does -Drun.jvmArguments=-Xdebug really mean

Tags: java, maven, debugging, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I can start my main Spring Boot application of the shelves in debug mode I can set a breakpoint in IntelliJ and it works! I.e. Running below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JasperApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JasperApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

However if I start my Spring Boot application in IntelliJ with the maven run plugin with debug option:

```
spring-boot:run
```

Debug does not work. I have read about

```
-Drun.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

I can't fit everything together, could someone enlightning me how it all works or direct me to some articles describing the whole thing under the hood.

I like to be able to run maven Spring Boot plugin from within IntelliJ aswell as the command line, being able to debug and set breakpoints. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `spring-boot:run` you are starting a remote process i.e. this process is **not** running inside your IDE.

If you want to debug this process from within your IDE the following pre requisites apply:

- The remote process must be 'remote debug aware', this is what you are doing when you run that process with `-Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"`
- You must use a remote debugger within your IDE. More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-remote.html) but the brief summary is:

  - Run > Edit Configurations
  - Click on the `+` icon and choose Remote
  - Name the run configuration and choose a module for the `Search sources using module's classpath`
  - The invoke `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"` and launch this Run configuration within your IDE and the two will talk to each other.

Here's a screenshot showing the remote run configuration looks like:

[image]